# How to change android requires section

Tags: android, google-play, version, publish

I recently uploaded an application to google play store. My application requires 4.0 and up. I decided that my application would be more suited to allow users with version 2.2 and up to download my app. In the android manifest

I changed `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />` to `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />`.

I released an update for my app but the android required still only allows api 14 and up. Any ideas what I should do?

Android Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="<packagename>"
android:versionCode="3"
android:versionName="1.2">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="false"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".main"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
           <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Post what you changed!

Comment: sorry not appearing, changed <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

to <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

Comment: Are you sure you are seeing the updated version when looking at in the play store. It can take ~2+ hours for the changes to replicate so you could still be looking at your old version

Comment: I'm looking at the APK details for the APK of the newest version that I uploaded

Comment: Play store has updated, though version is still Android 4.0 and up

Answer (score 0):

This change might not be instantaneous, wait a few hours until it gets updated on Play servers. Then you should be able to download to compatible phones with Android SDK 8 and above.

Comment: I noticed in the APK section of developer console that the number of supported devices is the same, and when I click on the new version the API levels is still 14+

Comment: Are you sure you compiled the **new** apk with these changes in your manifest and uploaded it?

Comment: Yes, I'll compile and upload the apk again to double check

Comment: Yes, still says API levels 14+ and same amount of supported devices

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with Android studio. To resolve the issue I had to change the min SDK version in the build.gradle file